# bash cat exclude multiple files based on grep results

Tags: bash

I have the following cat command that I use in a bash script. I look for $SAMPLE.txt file in subfolders 20* and combine them into 1 output.txt

`cat /$FOLDER/20*/$SAMPLE.txt > /$OUTPUTFOLDER/output.txt`

I now want to exclude certain files conditionally.

I found the following here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/246048/cat-files-except-one

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ cat -- !(DISCARD).txt > catKEPT
```

I want to do something like this.

Look for $SAMPLE and a pattern '$PAT1' in a $SAMPLEFILE. This $SAMPLEFILE is comma seperated. If there is a match, I want to store the first field of this line & use it to exclude files from cat

I would use this command to look for $SAMPLE and $PAT1 & then cut to keep my first field. I would assign that to a variable 'EXLUDE_FOLDER'

```
EXCLUDE_FOLDER=grep '$SAMPLE' $SAMPLEFILE | grep '$PAT1' | cut -d "," -f 1
```

And then use it like this

```
cat /$FOLDER/20*/$SAMPLE.txt -- !($FOLDER/$EXLUDE_FOLDER/$SAMPLE.txt) > /$OUTPUTFOLDER/output.txt
```

I'm stuck at putting this into an if/statement and dealing with situations where grep results in multiple matches, so multiple files should be excluded

Comment: I find your question very hard to understand - you want to look for `$PAT` in `$SAMPLE` with `$EXCLUDE` in `$FOLDER` obeying `$DISCARD`? Maybe you could say in straight English what you want to do? Maybe you could show what's in your `$SAMPLEFILE`. I can't even tell if you hope to produce a list of filenames, or the contents of some files! Sorry.

Comment: @MarkSetchell. $SAMPLEFILE is a .csv, with multiple lines and multiple fields, all comma seperated. In that file I want to look for lines that contain a string '$SAMPLE' and a string $PAT', hence the grep. For the lines that match, I want to store the first field in a variable EXCLUDE_FOLDER. The $EXCLUDE_FOLDER variable will then be used in a cat command in which I'm concatenating multiple text files into 1 output.txt, but excluding some files. Hope this makes it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

If `SAMPLE` and `PAT` are variables, you presumably want them expanded to their contents, which means you must put them in double quotes, not single quotes. Example:

```
SAMPLE=3

# Compare single quotes versus double
echo '$SAMPLE'              # outputs $SAMPLE
echo "$SAMPLE"              # outputs 3
```

If `SAMPLEFILE` is the name of a file, you must double-quote it, else it will fail if your filename has spaces in it, so you must use:

```
grep "$SAMPLE" "$SAMPLEFILE"
```

So, now you can test if your `grep` works like this:

```
grep "$SAMPLE" "$SAMPLEFILE" | grep "$PAT1" | cut -d "," -f 1
```

So, if that works, the next thing is that you want to capture **the output of** the command, so you need to use `$(...)`. That means:

```
EXCLUDE_FOLDER=$(grep "$SAMPLE" "$SAMPLEFILE" | grep "$PAT1" | cut -d "," -f 1)
```

So, see test if that works now:

```
echo "$EXCLUDE_FOLDER"
```

Comment: thanks for these adjustments, but as mentioned in the question I was merely stuck at dealing with situations where grep results in multiple matches, so multiple files should be excluded & how then to update my cat statement accordingly,